# Impact of the size of hosts.deny on network responsiveness

Tags: networking, performance

I intend to completely deny access to around 2000 IP addresses by adding proper entries in the **hosts.deny** file. Will this have an impact on the **responsiveness** of the system when accessed remotely by legitimate IPs?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

It will make the initial connection a fraction slower, but past that should have no bearing on the responsiveness once connected.

Generally speaking hosts.deny is pretty fast: on a test I just ran, a zero-length hosts.deny took 0.93 seconds to initiate and close an ssh connection ("time ssh testhost env").  With a 64,010-line hosts.deny (of the form "ALL: 10.10.x.y", with x and y running from 2 to 254), the same connection took 1.03 seconds.  All times were averaged over four samples.

Obviously your mileage may vary, and so I suggest you test, but I doubt you'll have serious problems.

Comment: It is indeed very fast. I had initially thought that a few thousand entries in hosts.deny would cause a noticeable connection delay, but this is not the case. Thanks for your answer.

Answer (score 2):

It is also possible to use iptables with connection tracking, which I think would be slightly faster and have the added benefit of being protocol agnostic, i.e being equally suited for denying connections to tcp/udp/icmp or whatever service you may be running.

Comment: Faster still would be pf tables.

Comment: @MattyB, @Jim: I was not aware that using iptables or pf tables on BSDs would have better performance. I always thought that tcpwrappers was the method of choice for this ind of access control, but apparently I was very wrong.

Answer (score 2):

- Can those 2000 addresses be aggregated down?

  `hosts.deny` will take CIDR definitions. So it should, for instance, be quicker and easier to manage:

  ```
  10.0.0.0/30
  10.0.1.0/30
  ```

  Than the equivalent:

  ```
  10.0.0.1
  10.0.0.2
  10.0.1.1
  10.0.1.2
  ```
- Does it warrant a firewall?

  If you're doing this a lot then it's really the duty of a firewall rather than the host itself. It would be easier to manage centrally and (as Jim notes) OpenBSD's PF with stateful tracking would make really light work of it.

Comment: @Dan: I checked pf and, to my surprise, I find it easier to maintain instead of iptables. Thanks

Comment: Good to hear. I love PF :)

Answer (score 1):

```
[olafrv@eqqus ~]$ cat /etc/hosts.deny | grep ^ALL | wc -l

8004
```

With that amount I have no problems and no delays on a Intel Desktop Dual Core PC.

The file hosts.deny is auto mantained wiht denyhosts (http://denyhosts.sourceforge.net)